# Cannot use type dvar float+ for the constraint

Tags: constraints, cplex

I am building a CPLEX OPL model. I found error

> Type Cannot use type dvar float+ for constraint.

form this variable type :

```
dvar float+     travel_time_p[plant][plant];
```

and constraint :

```
forall(p1 in plant,p2 in plant : p1!=p2)
      travel_time_p[p1][p2] = (distance_p[p1][p2])/velocity ;
```

how I write this constraint correctly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To express an equality constraint, one has to use `==` instead of `=`. So instead of

```
forall(p1 in plant,p2 in plant : p1!=p2)
      travel_time_p[p1][p2] = (distance_p[p1][p2])/velocity ;
```

can you try

```
 forall(p1 in plant,p2 in plant : p1!=p2)
       travel_time_p[p1][p2] == (distance_p[p1][p2])/velocity ;
```

?